# Line decoding error due to 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 8:' while reading log file line by line using python

Tags: python

I have a opened a file (log_file) on remote server using python sftp and trying read a log file line by line sing python but somehow in middle of some lines i am getting some ASCII characters as "^D^A^A^H ^B^A^D1" due to which  it pops an expection on that line due to decoding error.

`Exception : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 8: invalid start byte`

Can anyone help me out how to resolve this decoding error ?

```
for line in log_file:
    print(line)
    if 'LISTED FILES:' in line:
        result_date = re.search(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})',line)
```

Comment: it looks like the file wasn't saved as UTF-8. try to open the file in binary mode with `open(filepath, "rb")`, read the bytes of the problematic line and try to figure out which encoding was used

Comment: The file originally is of Ascii type...Have tried opening in binary mode but still the same issue.  ASCII text, with very long lines

Comment: If it were ASCII it could not contain the value `0xa9` (decimal `169`), since ASCII is a 7bit-code with values from from 0 to 127. So the file is not ASCII and you still have to find out what it is. Then open it in text mode and provide the encoding while doing that.

Comment: if you are getting the same error as before, you are either not opening the file in binary mode or you try to decode its content manually before executing the code you included in your question. otherwise, the if-condition would raise a `TypeError` before a decoding error occurs. comment out the if-block during debugging and don't try to decode the file content.